# Combining token based authentication with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

We currently have an internal API that uses Windows Authentication. I've been charged with looking into making this API public, and one of the requirements is that it should be possible to login without a domain user. Domain users should still be able to login, and should be considered super admins (access everything).

It is also clear that before long, we will need role or claim based authorization. As a prototype, I have implemented a system using ASP.NET Identity. Using JWT tokens and Claims based authorization.

But how do I ensure that users authenticated with Windows Authentication can skip the token step and simply use the API directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution where I add custom AuthorizationFilterAttributes to my endpoints. In the attribute, I check for the Principal type:

```
    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal is WindowsPrincipal)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
        //Custom logic here
        [...]
    }
```